# How can I subtract two weekly dates from each other in R?

Tags: r, date, week-number

I believe this question hasn't been answered for week dates, yet.

Suppose I have:

```
date1 <- '2015-W23'
date2 <- '2015-W30'
```

I want to compute the difference between these two dates as follows:

```
print(date1 - date2)
7
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: is any of the answers helpful? Upvote or accept if so

Answer (score 2):

How about using `tsibble` package?

```
library(tsibble)

yearweek('2015-W23') - yearweek('2015-W30')

Time difference of -7 weeks
```